# How to generate Proxy for WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, service, client

I have some legacy code here, which has a WCF Service.

The service is called by a client through a generatedProxy.cs

I thought it should be simple and wanted to generate my own 
proxy by using svcutil.exe, but I get lots of different errors,
depending on what I try (using running exe for download, using
assembly, using webconfig). For example the svcutil tells me 
that the service may not publish metadata (seems to me that
this is not true).

the webconfig has:

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
```

And it has a multisite binding

How can I generate such a proxy? Want to change some things in the contracts
and then have a current version of the proxy generated.

At the moment I have no service reference, as it has the some errors
when adding one as the svcutil does.

Any ideas?

-edit-
The services are published through a selfhosted service, quite similar to
the one in the WCF examples in the msdn. There are the endpoints for 
multiple services, which are implemented in dlls.

-edit 2-
Here is the app.config of the self hosting service
I have replaced some names, just to make it less special.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PersonDataModelContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/PersonDataModel.csdl|res://*/PersonDataModel.ssdl|res://*/PersonDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\PersonDatabase.sdf&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netMsmqBinding>
        <binding name="TransactionalNoSecurity" durable="true" exactlyOnce="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxRetryCycles="1" receiveRetryCount="20" retryCycleDelay="00:05:00">
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
      </netMsmqBinding>

      <basicHttpBinding>

        <binding name="TransportSecurity" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>

      <ws2007HttpBinding>

        <binding name="NoSecurity" transactionFlow="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="200000" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>

        <binding name="UNMessageSecurity" transactionFlow="true" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" establishSecurityContext="true"/>
          </security>
        </binding>

        <binding name="CertMessageSecurity" transactionFlow="true" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" establishSecurityContext="true"/>
          </security>
        </binding>

        <binding name="DomainMessageSecurity" transactionFlow="true" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" establishSecurityContext="true"/>
          </security>
        </binding>

        <binding name="RM_NoSecurity" transactionFlow="true" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
          <reliableSession enabled="true" ordered="false"/>
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
      </ws2007HttpBinding>

      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NoSecurity" transactionFlow="true">
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>


        <binding name="DomainMessageSecurity" transactionFlow="true" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>

        <binding name="CertMessageSecurity" transactionFlow="true" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SimpleServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" policyVersion="Policy15"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>

      <service name="MessagePlatform.LoggingService.GeneralLoggingService" behaviorConfiguration="SimpleServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="Logging" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="LoggingService" contract="MessagePlatform.LoggingService.Contracts.ILoggingService"/>

      </service>
      <service name="MessagePlatform.GatewayService.GeneralGatewayService" behaviorConfiguration="SimpleServiceBehavior">
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/"/>
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
          <endpoint address="gateway" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="GatewayService" contract="MessagePlatform.GatewayService.Contracts.IGatewayService"/>
          <endpoint address="gateway" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="Db2GatewayService" contract="MessagePlatform.GatewayService.Contracts.IDb2GatewayService"/>
          <endpoint address="gateway" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="Db1GatewayService" contract="MessagePlatform.GatewayService.Contracts.IDb1GatewayService"/>

          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

      </service>

    </services>
    <client>
      <endpoint name="LoggingServiceEP" address="http://localhost/Logging" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MessagePlatform.LoggingService.ILoggingService">        
      </endpoint>

      <endpoint name="GatewayServiceEP" address="http://localhost/gateway" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MessagePlatform.GatewayService.IGatewayService">
      </endpoint>

      <endpoint name="GatewayServiceDb2" address="http://localhost/gateway" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MessagePlatform.GatewayService.IDb2GatewayService">
      </endpoint>

      <endpoint name="GatewayServiceDb1" address="http://localhost/gateway" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MessagePlatform.GatewayService.IDb1GatewayService">
      </endpoint>

    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Also, if you're not changing the signature of the contracts you may be able to simply make the changes and recompile the DLL.

Comment: I want to add new methods, i.e. extend the existing ones. Will post the errors I get in a short time. The last one I got was something like "computer denies access to 127.0.0.1:8000". Thought of windows firewall, but it was not easily possible to disable it (possibly due to group policies, in the dialog there is a box with  "administrator protects you from changes here for your own security").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to enable the Metadata Exchange Endpoint so you can create a new proxy:

```
<service name="MessagePlatform.GatewayService.GeneralGatewayService" behaviorConfiguration="SimpleServiceBehavior">
  <host>
    <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/"/>
    </baseAddresses>
  </host>
  <endpoint address="gateway" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="GatewayService" contract="MessagePlatform.GatewayService.Contracts.IGatewayService"/>
  <endpoint address="gateway" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="Db2GatewayService" contract="MessagePlatform.GatewayService.Contracts.IDb2GatewayService"/>
  <endpoint address="gateway" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="Db1GatewayService" contract="MessagePlatform.GatewayService.Contracts.IDb1GatewayService"/>

  <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

</service>
```

and run

```
svcutil http://localhost:8000/mex
```

Comment: but there is already a generated client. somehow the former developers had to generate that. did not see any major changes in the config.

Comment: Will give it a try. The important line is the one with the "mex", right?

Comment: yes, it is an additional endpoint, you can remove it after you've created the proxy code.

Comment: still does not work. svcutil tells that it cannot load the exe as an assembly. all the endpoints are in that assembly, it is self hosting service as in the msdn examples.

Comment: can you post the entire serviceModel configuration?

Comment: Have updated my question to include the app.config, containing the service config. Hope this is what you want to see.

Comment: Added usage of the svc util to fetch the data from the url, and not from the dll.